# Ubuntu редактор и apache2.conf

Tags: ubuntu, apache, mod-rewrite

Люди!: VI - дань демонам ада, NANO - примитив для плебеев... Посоветуйте терминальный редактор для белых людей (с поиском, с копированием текста, с буфером).

У мя Убунта 22.04 сервер, php 8.1, apache2 последний.
Я получил ошибку выполнения апача с указанием на строку 229 в файле apache2.conf:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- а nano номера строк не показывает, это что мне - каждый раз по паре сотен нажатий стрелка вниз надо делать? - я так не играю...

Я нажал вниз 229 раз и обнаружил - что строк реально меньше! - может я ошибся...

На этом месте (в конце) находится моё изменение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- как советовано:

## a2enmod rewrite

## nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

В конце файла добавьте следующие строки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- что я сделал не так?

Comment: Используйте встроенный в mc редактор. Удобнее не знаю ничего. А по поводу конфига чувствую, что у вас директория дважды объявлена. Проверяйте *весь* конфиг.

Comment: А-а - продолжение Нортора и Фара - уважаю...

Хех! - так он сам предлагает использовать имеющиеся редакторы:
http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/kiss_13kb.1661150533.jpg

- наверное - mcedit.

Comment: Н-да.. - он далёк от Фар-а... - с буфером плохо работает...

Comment: Ну там изначально несколько раз объявлена Directory:

http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/kiss_47kb.1661150778.jpg

Comment: Ваша интуиция достойна восхищения

Подправил так:
http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/kiss_11kb.1661151260.jpg

- вроде стартонуло.

Comment: `а nano номера строк не показывает` - похоже кто-то хелп по программам не умеет читать.  
`-l --linenumbers Показывать номера строк перед текстом`

Comment: @Levontay mcedit я имел в виду